# UINavigationController pushviewcontroller memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a UITableiew listing n number of contacts and from Table view delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath I am navigating to a 'Contactview' UIViewController  by using **UINavigationController pushviewcontroller**.

For an instance if I navigate the first contact to Contactview, Live Bytes memory goes up from **1 MB to 3 MB**. Then when I tap on the back button the viewcontroller **delloc** method is called but the memory still stay around **2.95MB to 3MB** . My question is when the viewcontroller **delloc** method is called the memory of the viewcontoller  should be released right ?  Am I wrong anywhere ? Please suggest me if I am wrong. And I am using ARC project.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Yes it should.  Why don't you verify that dealloc is actually being called.

Comment: Yes I verified, and I am sure delloc method is called.

Comment: If you repeatedly push and pop view controllers, does memory continue to climb?

Comment: If we push and pop the same view controllers it is not climbing up but  if we push and pop the another view controllers the memory climb up and it is not reducing until we kill the application.

Comment: Do you have any images in the pushed view controller, by any chance?

Comment: Yes I have images in the pushed view controller.. Did I need to do something to release the image ??

Comment: Ah, see my answer posted below in that case. I suggest that for future questions you provide screenshots or more descriptions of the contents of views being pushed, so you can get help faster! :)

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer below if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you push your navigation back and forth and you see memory climbing unlimitedly, you have a memory management problem. **Even with ARC**, you may have *abandoned memory*. You can detect it using the Allocations template in Instruments.

1. In Instruments, put the application in a well-known starting state (for example, showing the table view).
2. Click **Mark Heap** button under Heapshot Analysis.
3. Navigate your controller back and forth once.
4. You will see a small increase in memory usage in the allocations graph. This is normal, internal caches may be storing some information.
5. Click the **Mark Heap** button again.
6. You will see a number of objects in the **Still Live** column.
7. Repeat steps 3-6 many times and see if there are "still living" objects after every iteration.

If there is an almost constant number of still living objects in each heapshot, click the right arrow button in one of the heapshots and you will see all the objects that are still living. Look for objects probably created by you, select one, expand it, and select its memory address with a simple click. Then click the **Extended Detail** button to see a stack trace showing where the object was allocated. With this code context I'm sure you will understand why your memory was abandoned.

Comment: It also helps to turn on "Record reference counts" in the Allocation tools settings (View -> Inspectors -> Show Record Settings). This shows where retain/release happens. In my case, this quickly showed I had a strong delegate causing a reference cycle (X.delegate = self; self.tableCell = X).

Answer (score 0):

See.. one thing ARC will release it the contents some where in future right.Its Automatic right.. how can expect the ARC to do the Gatrbage collection after class will disappear.It might take time to free the memory.

Comment: I believe ARC isn't Garbage Collection as such, and isn't subject to Java-like GC behaviour. Automatic Reference Counting is a compile-time memory management tool, rather than a runtime GC! As far as I know, anyway.

Comment: @JonathanZhan You are correct. ARC is only adding the appropriate memory management calls for you. Garbage collection is not available in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check retainCount? is that showing your desired value?

Comment: You should never check the retainCount - its value is not well-defined for certain types of classes, and might not reflect the actual state of the object properly.

Answer (score 0):

UIImage caches images for you as an optimisation, so this is expected behaviour.

If you wish to confirm that this is the case, for peace of mind, you can force a low memory warning (Under the Hardware menu for the simulator). This should get UIImage to throw out its cache.

You can also use this private method, but of course throw it out before submission.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)];
```

Comment: So I should call   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)]; when I pop the view controller.. right ?

Comment: Ah. Well what I would suggest is that you set it up so that you run that method on a button press or something similar that you can control. Increase your memory usage as before, then simulate the memory warning and see if your memory usage drops. If it *does* drop, then don't worry because everything is working as intended. Keep on coding, when your app needs more memory the images will automatically be freed up in the normal course of events.

Answer (score 0):

You might own a strong reference for the view controller elsewhere in the code. You should be sure if it's really deallocated... If any other object has reference to it beyond the navigation controller it won't be deallocated.  Try override dealloc. (You could override dealloc in an ARC project as well, you are only not allowed to use retain count manipulation calls.) To be sure if dealloc is called put some logging or something debugable code into that method.